# (php,mysqli,phpmyadmin) Can I insert records into my table on this way?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I cant find the mistake but this code doesn't work. It always shows me an `"error de envio"` (sending error) on this part:

```
...or die("error de envio");
```

phpMyAdmin data:

[image: phpMyAdmin data]

---

My PHP code:

```
$link =mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","usuario")or die("
<h2>NO se encuentra el servidor </h2>");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$nick=$_POST['nick'];
$email=$_POST['correo'];
$raza=$_POST['raza'];

$req =(strlen($nick)*strlen($pass)*strlen($email))or die("<h2>no se llenaron los datos </h2>");

$contra=md5($pass);

mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM usuario");
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nombre`,`contrasena`,`usuario`,`email`,`raza`) VALUES('$name','$contra','$nick','$email','$raza')") or die("error de envio");
echo"gracias por registrarse" 
mysqli_close($link);
```

Can I enter my data this way?

Comment: 1) Screenshots are evil, everybody hates them. In your case, it would be better to explain your table structure by inserting its `CREATE TABLE` command. 2) All capital nicks seem bad on the first spot, I suggest to become simply "Gabriel Garcia Castro".

Answer (score 0):

You have `usuar` column in table not `usuario` that use in query.

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nombre`,`contrasena`,`usuar`,`email`,`raza`) VALUES('$name','$contra','$nick','$email','$raza')") or die("error de envio");
```

Note: You can see mysql error with [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function.

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `usuario`(`nombre`,`contrasena`,`usuario`,`email`,`raza`) VALUES('$name','$contra','$nick','$email','$raza')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```